# Create with TikZ a union of more graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created this morning with Geogebra this figure

[image]

There are two function:

> f(x)=-2/3 π G ρ (3a² - x²) (green parabola)
>
> g(x)=-4/3 π G ρ (1/x) a³ (blue function)

where ρ is the density of a sphere, a is the radius of the sphere and 0<=x=r<=a or r>=a. r is the distance of a generic point. I have export the code with TikZ but it is not very beautiful graph. Since `tikz` is more precise how could I recreate the following two graphs ((1) and (2)) with TikZ the same that I have created with Adobe Illustrator?

**Graph 1**

[image]

**Graph 2**

[image]

Greetings.

Comment: Hmmh, what precisely is the question? It seems that you are able to draw the plots, so are you asking how to add the annotations? (BTW, I am also wondering if the `R` in the lower line in equation (20) should not be an `a` instead.)

Comment: Hi, with affect. If it possible create the same figure that I have created with Adobe Illustrator. No marmot the formulas are correct. I'm writing some notes about Mathematical Methods for physics. If my question is not clear, would you please edit my question?

Comment: Note there are two places where it says `domain=-2.118707736780596:5.255760268305019`. If I understand you correctly, you want to change the first one to domain=`-2.118707736780596:1` and the second one to `domain=1:5.255760268305019`. You can probably set the domain of the functions in GeoGebra as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hi, yes exact. I have added now the last image (my original notes).

Comment: I don't really see the point of the original notes, just state clearly in the question what you want to change about the existing code, what is wrong with the output you currently have. Yes, we can compare your images, but it is easier if you also say what you want to do.

Comment: I would like to recreate the same images with TikZ.

Comment: @Sebastiano Since you presumably know about `pgfplots` why try to make some code using that and then post that code as your starting point.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes of course. But I don't know, now, how to create functions for traits.

Comment: But you already have the functions. Probably you want to draw them with `\addplot`, though. And I also do not know anything about GeoCobra, but the issue with automatized TeX code generation is that the code, well, looks as if it was written by a machine. It is probably much easier to do these from scratch.

Comment: @marmot Do you think that what I created with adobe illustrator is okay? So I remove my question and I apologise to you all for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not an answer (also because I do not understand the question). What I did is, as suggested by Torbjørn T. to restrict the domain in the first plot and also to replace the Ti*k*Z `plot` commands by `\addplot`. (There is nothing wrong with the Ti*k*Z `plot` commands, but since you're loading pgfplots anyway, it might be more appropriate to use `\addplot`.) I also drew something along the lines of your second plot, trusting that you got the slope in the first plot right.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% \usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{rgb}{1.,0.,0.}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.,0.,1.}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0.,0.39215686274509803,0.}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-2.118707736780596,
xmax=5.255760268305019,
ymin=-4.168187134916317,
ymax=0.14792878906557064,
xtick={-2.0,-1.0,...,5.0},
ytick={-4.0,-3.0,...,0.0},]
\clip(-2.118707736780596,-4.168187134916317) rectangle (5.255760268305019,0.14792878906557064);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.811006812257485,-1.2289916284010438) -- (10.458930692000973,-1.2289916284010438);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.78452757346005,-2.261681941501005) -- (10.432451453203537,-2.261681941501005);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.7977671928587675,-1.7453367849510244) -- (10.445691072602255,-1.7453367849510244);
\addplot[line width=2.pt,color=qqwuqq,smooth,samples=100,domain=-2.118707736780596:1] 
{0-2.0/3.0*3.141592653589793*0.05*10.2*(3.0*1.0^(2.0)-(x)^(2.0))};
\addplot[line width=2.pt,color=qqqqff,smooth,samples=100,domain=1:5.255760268305019] 
{0-4.0/3.0*3.141592653589793*0.05*10.2*1.0/(\x)*1.0^(3.0)};
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-4.168187134916317) -- (1.,0.14792878906557064);
\addplot[line width=2.pt,color=ffqqqq,domain=-2.118707736780596:5.255760268305019] 
{(-4.272566012175239--2.1362830077341797*\x)/1.};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (9.187927229724098,-0.9178605725311839) node {$a = 1$};
\draw[color=black] (8.062559580833117,-1.9505508856311446) node {$G = 0.05$};
\draw[color=black] (8.76425940896514,-1.4342057290811645) node {$\rho = 10.2$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.8539153488062472,-0.7589851397465746) node {$f$};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (0.5027369041654571,-6.518219578188664) node {$g$};
\draw[color=black] (1.2044367322974814,-1.9902697438272972) node {$A$};
\draw[color=ffqqqq] (1.9061365604295057,-0.6001097069619652) node {$i$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-2.118707736780596,
xmax=5.255760268305019,
ymin=-4.168187134916317,
ymax=0.14792878906557064,
xtick={-2.0,-1.0,...,5.0},
ytick={-4.0,-3.0,...,0.0},]
\clip(-2.118707736780596,-4.168187134916317) rectangle (5.255760268305019,0.14792878906557064);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.811006812257485,-1.2289916284010438) -- (10.458930692000973,-1.2289916284010438);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.78452757346005,-2.261681941501005) -- (10.432451453203537,-2.261681941501005);
% \draw[line width=4.pt] (7.7977671928587675,-1.7453367849510244) -- (10.445691072602255,-1.7453367849510244);
\addplot[line width=2.pt,color=qqqqff,smooth,samples=100,domain=1:5.255760268305019] 
{0-4.0/3.0*3.141592653589793*0.05*10.2*1.0/(\x)*1.0^(3.0)};
\draw [line width=1.2pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt] (1.,-4.168187134916317) -- (1.,0.14792878906557064);
\addplot[line width=2.pt,color=qqwuqq,domain=-2.118707736780596:1] 
{(-4.272566012175239-2.1362830077341797*(\x-2))/1.};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[color=black] (9.187927229724098,-0.9178605725311839) node {$a = 1$};
\draw[color=black] (8.062559580833117,-1.9505508856311446) node {$G = 0.05$};
\draw[color=black] (8.76425940896514,-1.4342057290811645) node {$\rho = 10.2$};
\draw[color=qqwuqq] (-1.8539153488062472,-0.7589851397465746) node {$f$};
\draw[color=qqqqff] (0.5027369041654571,-6.518219578188664) node {$g$};
\draw[color=black] (1.2044367322974814,-1.9902697438272972) node {$A$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]